# uncertain on using sphinx for these queries

Tags: mysql, sphinx

How much can a engine like Sphinx help to find a small set of rows when you are comparing multiple columns instead of doing a full text search.

As an example, we have a database for each client. Many of these have 10million + user rows. The issue is that most of these rows represent 1 time logins instead of real users (insert 100 different reasons why this is bad, but these are decisions made by people not me).
A "real" user can be differentiated from a login or other type of user by doing string comparisons on 3 different columns. (Earlier I excluded full text because these are small values - usually in the 10-15 character range but never over 32).

Would a tool like Sphinx be a good choice for queries that only want 1 type of user?

Answer (score 0):

Well sphinx might help to that, but only because it provides a way to do a sort of "materialized view".

... ie can do a big complicated query, composing your 'comparisons' probably as a JOIN in a complicated database query. Create an aggregation of all the data (even these single logins). A query that might take a LONG time to execute. the 'indexer' tool, as some functions that make running lots of small queries to compose a big index.

Ie still doing the grunt work in the database and just saving the result in a sphinx index. Sphinx just helps a bit with composing into a single index (or view)

... can then do arbitrary queries, on the the sphinx index, eg to just list 'real' users.
Ie can do 'fast' queries, on the 'intermediate' data stored in sphinx.

But in that way, sphinx doesnt offer much advantage, to just doing the materialized view in mysql directly. ie could save the intermediate data in mysql directly, and run queries there.

Not really doing anything that CANT be done with mysql, just possibly doing it 'easier' with sphinx.